# User permission from Content database

Tags: permissions, user, content-database, sql-query

I am having copy of content database from client. Now i need to find permission level for particular user using SQL query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all never query content database. You will end up violating your license.
2. Restore the content database and attach it to a web application.
3. Use Powershell or Visual Studio to write a small piece of code to query the SPSite object against the user  who permissions needs to be identified.

I would recommend to go for this simple powershell script available in codeplex that will suffice for the requirement you mentioned.

http://sharepointpsscripts.codeplex.com/downloads/get/94684